# How To Remove Ubuntu Studio Software

Tags: sound, uninstall, ubuntu-studio

So I added the "Ubuntu Studio Audio", "Ubuntu Studio Menu", and the "Low Latency Kernel" from the Ubuntu Studio software installer. It added a bunch of things that I don't need and messed up my clean system. How would I remove all the things it added?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I fixed this is f*cking amazing. Thanks for not helping and down voting guys.

First, remove as much of those apps from the software center as possible.
Then, search for one of those useless apps from search and open folder location. Delete all of the ones you don't need by chowing the folder. After that, go to the main menu settings and remove the options ubuntu added